# try to resize the stream image with sharp Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework, chatbot

I am trying to resize the width and height of input Stream-image from the user to the server with sharp function but nothing happens with the image. It keeps on his original size, How should I use the sharp function so that I can get the image smaller or bigger?

Please help me

**This is how my code looks like:**

```js
'use strict';


const builder = require('botbuilder');
const restify = require('restify');
const utils = require('./utils.js');
const request = require('request');
const sharp = require('sharp');
const fs = require('fs');     
const resizeImage = require('resize-image');


// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
const connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

// Setup Restify Server
const server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, () => {
    console.log(`${server.name} listening to ${server.url}`);
});

// Listen for messages from users
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

// default dialog

//resize the images

//Sends greeting message when the bot is first added to a conversation
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
    if (message.membersAdded) {
        message.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
            if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
                
         
                var reply = new builder.Message()
                    .address(message.address)
                    
                    .text('Hi, please send a screenshot for the error');
                    

                bot.send(reply);
            }
        });
    }
}
);

bot.dialog('/', function(session) {
    if(utils.hasImageAttachment(session)){
        //--others

        var stream = utils.getImageStreamFromMessage(session.message);
      ***//resize the image stream
      sharp('stream')
      .resize(100, 100)
      .toFile('stream', function(err) {
        // output.jpg is a 200 pixels wide and 200 pixels high image
        // containing a scaled and cropped version of input.jpg
      }); 
      //***
        const params = {
            'language': 'en',
            'detectOrientation': 'true',

        };
        const options = {
            uri: uriBase,
          qs: params,
            body: stream ,
          
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscriptionKey
            }
        };

request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
      return;
    }

 const obj =   JSON.parse(body);
 console.log(obj);

 
  //------------ get the texts from json as string
  if(obj.regions =="" ){
    
    session.send('OOOOPS I CANNOT READ ANYTHING IN THISE IMAGE :(');

}else{


let buf = ''
if(obj && obj.regions) {
obj.regions.forEach((a, b, c) => {
if(a && a.lines) {
a.lines.forEach((p, q, r) => {
if(p && p.words) {
p.words.forEach((x, y, z) => {
  

buf += ` ${x.text}  ` 



})
}
})
}
})
}
session.send(buf);
}

});
               

    } else {
        session.send('nothing');

        
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According the doc of Sharp of function [`toFile()`](http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/api-output/#tofile), this function returns a promise when no callback is provided.

So there should be no I/O block when excusing `toFile` function, and continue runing the following code which is `request.post` in your code snippet. At that time, the image may not be modified.

You can try to either use promise style code flow, like:

```
sharp('stream')
      .resize(100, 100)
      .toFile('stream')
      .then((err,info)=>{
         //do request post 
      })
```

or put the request code inside the callback function of `toFile()`, like:

```
sharp('stream')
      .resize(100, 100)
      .toFile('stream',function(err,info)=>{
       //do request post
      })
```

Comment: thanks for the response and your time. I tried it but it does not work. i am getting the same result. the size of the input image cannt be modified. Is there another function or trick which can help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of sharp('stream') doesn't work because the function is looking for a string as its input and you are trying to feed it a stream. Per the [docs](http://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/api-constructor/), you need to read from the readableStream and then process the image.

The example below I tested (locally) and runs. As is, it will save the image file on the server in the location of the app.js file. The commented-out ".pipe(stream)" creates a writeableStream you could then access at a later point if that is what you need. In that case, you wouldn't use .toFile().

Hope of help!

```
bot.dialog('/', function (session) {
    if (utils.hasImageAttachment(session)) {
        //--others

        var stream = utils.getImageStreamFromMessage(session.message);

        var transformer = sharp()
            .resize(100)
            .jpeg()
            .toFile('image.jpg', function (err) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
            })
            .on('info', function (err, info) {
                session.send('Image height is ' + info.height);
            });
        stream.pipe(transformer); //.pipe(stream);

        const params = {
            'language': 'en',
            'detectOrientation': 'true',

        };

        const options = {
            uri: "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apis",
            qs: params,
            body: stream,

            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': ""
            }
        };

        request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Error: ', error);
                return;
            }

            console.log(body);
            const obj = JSON.stringify(body);
            console.log(body);


            //------------ get the texts from json as string
            if (obj.regions == "") {
                session.send('OOOOPS I CANNOT READ ANYTHING IN THISE IMAGE :(');
            } else {
                let buf = ''
                if (obj && obj.regions) {
                    obj.regions.forEach((a, b, c) => {
                        if (a && a.lines) {
                            a.lines.forEach((p, q, r) => {
                                if (p && p.words) {
                                    p.words.forEach((x, y, z) => {
                                        buf += ` ${x.text}  `
                                    })
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
                session.send(buf);
            }
        });
    } else {
        session.send('nothing');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used Sharp in the below way in my case which works perfectly fine.

```
            sharp('stream')
            .png()
            .resize(100, 100)
            .toBuffer((err, buffer, info) => {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);

                if (buffer) {
                    return buffer;
                }
            });
```

Sharp's **toFile()** saves the output in a file, so you could give a file name as an argument. **toBuffer()** will return a buffered object.
Hope it helps!

Comment: I am trying to resize aws s3 stream. In my case it is saying `Input file is missing`